# How do I display duplicating texting once using streamline?

Tags: python, streamlit

```
    st.write('Residual = ', format(RR1,'.3E'), 'Minimum = ',         format(MIN,'.3E'), '          ', end="\r")
```

When I put print instead of st.write it works fine but I want it to be displayed on streamlit as a way of the user to be able to keep track of when the app is about to be done doing calculations.

Comment: What is the problem? You have an error? The text is not displayed in your app? Also, what do you mean by "duplicating" in the title?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
with st.empty():
```

at the beginning of the while loop that is going to display the result and use the `end="\r"` at the end of each print statement or st.write statement to clear the text each time the new one is ready to be displayed.